# Is there a way to disable mathjax in a comment

Tags: support, formatting

I recently tried posting a comment of:

`The comparison gets even more muddled if you look at cost/launch where NASA's paying SpaceX $1.6bn/12 launches works out to $133m/launch, or about 2.4x what they're advertising for commercial sales; much smaller than the 20x from your price per kg numbers. The disparity is a combination of the ISS being in an awkward orbit, ISS cargo being volume rather than mass limited, and (I think) the 20,000kg number not including the mass of the dragon capsule that carries the delivered cargo.`

but the combination of $ and / chracters resulted in it being formatted as:

> The comparison gets even more muddled if you look at cost/launch where NASA's paying SpaceX $1.6bn/12 launches works out to $133m/launch, or about 2.4x what they're advertising for commercial sales; much smaller than the 20x from your price per kg numbers. The disparity is a combination of the ISS being in an awkward orbit, ISS cargo being volume rather than mass limited, and (I think) the 20,000kg number not including the mass of the dragon capsule that carries the delivered cargo.

After a few edits I got it to:

The comparison gets even more muddled if you look at cost/launch where NASA's paying SpaceX 1.6bn dollars for 12 launches works out to $133m per launch, or about 2.4x what they're advertising for commercial sales; much smaller than the 20x from your price per kg numbers. The disparity is a combination of the ISS being in an awkward orbit, ISS cargo being volume rather than mass limited, and (I think) the 20,000kg number not including the mass of the dragon capsule that carries the delivered cargo.

...which wasn't mistaken for additional markup and mangled as a result.  Was there I way I could've gotten the same result without having to remove most of the dollar and slash characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, but you can bypass it by using `\$` instead of `$` alone where the dollar signs are needed. Same goes for normal posts (questions and answers). If you can't edit your comment any more, then flag the post you've left it under (you can't flag your own posts) for moderator's attention, explain what needs to be done and someone will make sure it's sorted out for you. Please also flag like so comment and posts of others where you see they need to be edited, we likely still have some left from the "pre-MathJax era" that need to be reformatted. ;)

Comment: Looks like someone else found and edited the comment for me before I saw your reply...